# add UIImage to mglmapview using MGLStyleLayer+MGLImageSource shows garbage on map

Tags: mapbox-ios, mapbox-ios-maps

I am showing geo-referenced images on an mglmapview using an MGLStyleLayer created with an MGLImageSource that specifies a UIImage that has a height of 3000. The MGLStyleLayer is added to the map using [map.style insertlayer ...];

This is working fine for all my UIImages but they all have heights < 3000. With this 3000 height UIImage I see a garbage image on my map. It contains snippets of other images I use on the map (mostly images used in point annotations). If I shrink the UIImage down to a height of 2000 it works OK.

My openGL is a little rusty but it looks to me like the mapview is using a texture array for all these images and the array has a max image height that I am overstepping. Just a guess.

Is there a known max height for images used in an MGLImageSource? Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: I got around this issue by tiling my images. but I would still like to know what was going on if anyone can offer some insight.